# Algorithm to add a path point, preserving path shape?

Tags: bezier-curve

I'm using [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/) and need to add a point to a curved path without affecting the path's shape. Inkscape's "Edit paths by nodes" tool has this feature by default -- double-clicking on a path adds a node, adjusting the handles of the new node and adjacent nodes to preserve the path shape. What appears to be [the code](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/blob/master/src/ui/tool/node.cpp#L940) says "Handle lengths are equal to 1/3 of the distance from the adjacent node." I haven't managed to find the code which updates the handles of the adjacent nodes, but observing the behavior in Inkscape they appear to shrink to an amount proportional to the (along-path) distance to the new node.

Coding this up, it works well on [a circle](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) but isn't quite right for [a less regular shape](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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).

Any suggestions for making it work as reliably as Inkscape?

Answer (score 2):

I realized this would be better phrased as "how to split a bezier curve", answered well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36434774/362702) (De Casteljau's Algorithm).

And I had somehow missed that it's implemented in paper.js as [Path.divideAt](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#divideat-location)